# ASIHTTPRequest misses files

Tags: file, download, asihttprequest

I'm using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) to download a list of 30 files but 2 or 3 (different) are always lost.

Is it possible set the maximum number of connections per seconds?? I've tried with

```
- [[ASIHTTPRequest sharedQueue]  setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];  
- [cola setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
```

But i don't have any luck...

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: Could you give us a little more info -- what does the code look like that sets up the requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem with:

```
[request setPersistentConnectionTimeoutSeconds:80];

[request setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:NO];
```

The problem may be that Apache installed doesnt support persistent connections.

See Configuring persistent connections section in http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use for more info.